# Value Map Attributes to Multiple Files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, domains

I am hoping someone can share a way that I can some what automatically (none manual) associate a pre-defined CSV file for use with multiple shapefiles as an attribute Value Map.

I have a number (in the hundreds) of shapefiles that have the same attributes (Type1 and Type2).  Both Type1 and Type2 are numeric codes and I will like to apply text descriptions to them.  I have generated a CSV file that has the value and description.  What I am wondering is, is there a way to apply this CSV to all my shapefiles automatically, or will I have to open each file and associate the CSV file through the Properties dialog.

If there is an alternative method that would provide the same results I would be willing to give it a try.

Thanks...

Comment: So you want to automate the setting of Value Map?

Comment: Yes, to a degree.  For example, I have a layer called urban_poly, and I need to tile it up into 100 pieces.  I want to have all those 100 tiles have the same Value Map association (from the CSV).  But I don't want to have to open each file to do the association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a Python script. I just wrote one for a different goal (generate several maps, based on the same shape file and CSV file, but with different fields). The same trick might be used for your problem. My script uses a modified project file to generate a series of project files, based on a list of field names. You could try this method by varying the name of the shape file instead.

My script can be found here: http://www.qgis.nl/media/2013/08/PythonSnapshots.zip and is described in this article: http://www.qgis.nl/2013/08/13/python-script-to-generate-series-of-maps/?lang=en.